# When to use .byte over .ascii

Tags: assembly, mips

Let's say I want to declare a variable like "u", which is one character. Why would I want to use .byte instead of .ascii?

Wouldn't a single ascii character also be 1 byte long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single ASCII character, you might well choose either `.ascii "u"` or `.byte 'u'`.  Both will assemble to one byte at the current position.  That's the one use-case where `.ascii` and `.byte`'s functionality pretty much overlaps.

For human readers, some might read the `.ascii` as `char foo[1] = {'u'};` vs. the `.byte` being like `char bar = 'u';`, but in asm that's just a semantic difference.  Both are 1-byte objects with the same object-representation, and unlike C there's nothing that will implicitly dereference one to get the value there vs. the name being the address for the array.

---

`.byte` allows non-ASCII values conveniently, like `.byte 1, 2, 3`, to implement C
`uint8_t arr[] = {1,2,3};`

You could equivalently write `.ascii "\x01\x02\x03"` if your assembler supports hex escape codes (GAS or clang), but for human readers the `.byte` version looks a lot more like C.

`.byte` also allows signed negative values like `-2` without having to manually work out the 2's complement bit-pattern like `.ascii "\xFE"`.

For text strings longer than 1 byte, `.ascii "abc"` is of course more convenient than
`.byte 'a', 'b', 'c'`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This clears it up for me!